# Record audio from Microphone in Android 2.3.4 on SGS2

Tags: java, android, audio

Hello i have this class for recording audio stream from the mic

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

public class AudioRecorder {

final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
public final String path;

public AudioRecorder(String path) {
    this.path = sanitizePath(path); 
}

private String sanitizePath(String path) {
    if (!path.startsWith("/")) {
        path = "/" + path;
    }
    if (!path.contains(".")) {
        path += ".3gp";
    }
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            + path;
}

public void start() throws IOException {
    String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state
                + ".");
    }

    // make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
    File directory = new File(path).getParentFile();
    if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
        throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
    }

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(path);
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error: recorder - ",e.toString());
    }
    recorder.start();
}

public void stop() throws IOException {

    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();

}

public void playarcoding(String path) throws IOException {
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setDataSource(path);
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
    mp.setVolume(10, 10);
}
```

}

in my activity i used it like this

```
AudioRecorder ar = new AudioRecorder("/sdcard/a.3gp");
     if(addButton.getText() != "running"){
         try { 
            ar.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error:",e.toString());
        }
        addButton.setText("running");
     }
     else{
         try {
            ar.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error:",e.toString());
        }
     }
```

i also put this permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

after i push the button on the activity i think it is starting to record 
the problem is when i try to stop it...
when i push the button again to stop it it brings this error:

```
stop called in an invalid state: 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

can anybody explain please why this is happening and also how can i fix this, cause i googled 
for it and did not found a solution.

this happens in the stop function of the recorder.